# Why does Github look like this?

Tags: github

The whole site looks like this for me. I can't find any answers online as to why...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is probably your internet connection is slow.

Trying opening the website in some other browser and see if you still face the same issue.

Comment: Nope, I'm getting 190 MB/s right now. Just tried in Edge and it looks the same.

Comment: Is there any extensions or softwares that does the job ad block? Sometimes ad blocking softwares tend to do like these kinda stuff for me.